# Geometrically determine maximal quadrilateral in given square

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

We have given square $ABCD$. Line $p$ through point $A$ intersects side $DC$ in point $Q$. Let point $M$ be on side $AB$ and point $N$ on side $BC$, such that line $MN$ is parallel to $p$.

> Where should we place point $M$ to maximize the area of quadrilateral $AMNQ$?

I solved given problem analytical, but now I have to solve it geometrically and I have no idea how.

[image]

Comment: Is $Q$ fixed? If not, then the maximum area of $AMNQ$ is when $Q=D$ and $M=B$ and thus $AMNQ=ABCD$

Comment: Maybe I should've stated that `AMNQ != ABCD`. Points `Q` and `M` are not fixed and should be determined.

Comment: Suppose the vertices are points in a coordinate system, then the largest quadrilateral not $ABCD$ is STILL when $Q,M$ are infinitesimally close to $D,B$, respectively.